# What happened to nsurlstoraged, the successor to cookied?

Tags: macos, cookies

According to the answer on [How to delete Safari cookies from OS 10.7.2 terminal?](https://superuser.com/a/1203145/11116) and many others there used to be a daemon called `cookied` later replaced with `nsurlstoraged`.

I don't see `nsurlstoraged` on my Mac install in the process table or on disk. Did this go away? If so, what replaced this functionality? What is responsible for writing `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies` on OSX 13.5+?

---

What I'm trying to do: I can delete `Cookies.binarycookies`. I can go to a site like `setcookie.net` I can fill out that page, I can hit refresh. The `Cookies.binarycookies` does not get regenerated. I want to know *why*. I can figure out that, but I need a pointer: what writes to that file today. Previously someone asked this very question and they were told they needed to kill `pkill -U $(whoami) cookiesd`. Then it turned out that daemon was renamed to `nsurlstoraged`, and that needed to be killed. Now I don't have that. Be careful though, my end goal is to understand the system I am using.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also, according to which question?

Comment: @benwiggy I want to find the replacement task to nsurlstoraged so I can understand how cookies are working with Safari and what I have to kill after I `rm ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies` to get a new binarycookie file to be generated.

Comment: @nohillside edited that in, forgot to paste the link

Comment: Does it have to be from Terminal? Cookies are easy enough to clear for one site or all from within Safari itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin no, I don't even care about that. I want to know how cookies work on OSX and what replaced `nsurlstoraged` as the cookie daemon.

Comment: OK, let's try this another way… a) What OS? b) What *practical* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm on 13.5, I already answered that question.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466143/what-happened-to-nsurlstoraged-the-successor-to-cookied?noredirect=1#comment689689_466143

Comment: @Tetsujin your screenshot shows nsurl**sessiond**, not nsurl**storaged**.

Comment: I've updated this question with **MUCH** more information, but again I'm looking to understand how this system works.

Comment: meh, OK. I'm out, then. Good luck.

Comment: @Tetsujin darn, i though you had something there =( If you want to investigate, by all means it's appreciated.